# Prove that if $\{x_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ satisfies the given condition and converges, it must converge to 5.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that a sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ can have the following condition: $$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(\exists m > n)(x_m = 5)$$

I'm trying to prove that if $\{x_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ satisfies that above condition and converges, it must converge to 5.

My thought would be that if there must exists an $m$ such that $x_m = 5$ in such a sequence, then there are either many 5s interspersed throughout the sequence or it's a sequence of 5s. In any case, if some value of $x$ is 5 at the tail of the sequence, then it can't be a lone outlier because the sequence is converging. Hence the entire sequence must be close to five as $x$ approaches infinity. Hence it should be converging to 5.

I'm not sure how to express this more formally. Does anyone see a better way to prove this?

Comment: Can you say that you can construct a subsequence converging to 5? And since every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to same limit of the sequence, limit must be 5.

Comment: Three times instead of `_{n=1}` you had `_\mathrm{n=1}`. In none of those instances did that make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the condition $\forall n\,\exists m>n\, x_m=5.$ That is not enough to guarantee convergence, as seen by this example:
$$
3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,\ldots
$$
But next you say **"and converges."** That means there is some number to which it converges. Call that limit $\ell.$ Either $\ell=5$ or $\ell\ne5.$ Suppose the latter. Let $\varepsilon$ be half the distance between $\ell$ and $5,$ i.e. $\varepsilon = |\ell-5|.$ Then $\exists N\,\forall k>n\, |x_k-\ell|<\varepsilon,$ i.e. the distance between $x_k$ and $\ell$ is less than $\varepsilon$. So $\ell-\varepsilon<x_k<\ell+\varepsilon.$ But $5$ is not between $\ell\pm\varepsilon.$ (You can prove that via the triangle inequality.) So $x_k\ne 5$ and you have a contradiction.

Comment: Why is this answer incorrect?

Comment: @BobMcdonald : It's not incorrect, but maybe someone was unable to understand it and therefore down-voted it.